# Serializing Entity Relation only to Id with JMS Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to serialize a entity relation with JMS Serializer.

Here is the Entity:

```
class Ad
{ 

    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @Groups({"manage"})
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @Type("Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country")
     * @Groups({"manage"})
     * 
     * @var \Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @Groups({"manage"})
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Ad
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country $country
     * @return Ad
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country= $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Ad
     */
    public function setTituloanuncio($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

}
```

And the Entity of the relationship:

```
class Country
{

    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @Groups("manage")
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @Groups("admin")
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * Set description
     * @Groups("")
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setDescripcionpais($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I serialize the entity but I don't know how to convert the country attribute into a simple field.

I get this result in json:

```
{"description":"foo", "title":"bar", "country":{"id":"en"} }
```

But I want to get the id field of the country like this:

```
{"description":"foo", "title":"bar", "country": "en" }
```

It is possible with JMS Serializer?

Thank you.

**[EDIT]**

@VirtualProperty doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you could use `@VirtualProperty` annotation:

```
/**
 * @VirtualProperty
 * @SerializedName("foo")
 */
public function bar()
{
    return $this->country->getCode();
}
```

But be aware when it comes to deserialization:

> @VirtualProperty This annotation can be defined on a method to
>   indicate that the data returned by the method should appear like a
>   property of the object.
>
> **> Note: This only works for serialization and is completely ignored
>   during deserialization.**

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you! Perfect for me. I just needed to serialize.

Comment: I apologize, I was on a vacation and didn't have access to Internet. I noticed that you unaccepted then accepted answer. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, I've gotten it to work. The problem was that I had not saved the Country object in the object ad. Thank you very much.

Comment: YAML config reference also got updated:
https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/commit/e104873368b8ca22ac057f76086c6a4fce5c7033

Answer (score 19):

Just to follow answered question:

If you don't like writing one method for each relation you have - just write your own handler. It's easy like

```
final class RelationsHandler
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * RelationsHandler constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager) { $this->manager = $manager; }


    public function serializeRelation(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, $relation, array $type, Context $context)
    {
        if ($relation instanceof \Traversable) {
            $relation = iterator_to_array($relation);
        }

        if (is_array($relation)) {
            return array_map([$this, 'getSingleEntityRelation'], $relation);
        }

        return $this->getSingleEntityRelation($relation);
    }

    /**
     * @param $relation
     *
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    protected function getSingleEntityRelation($relation)
    {
        $metadata = $this->manager->getClassMetadata(get_class($relation));

        $ids = $metadata->getIdentifierValues($relation);
        if (!$metadata->isIdentifierComposite) {
            $ids = array_shift($ids);
        }

        return $ids;
    }
}
```

Register the Handler

```
  jms_serializer.handler.relation:
      class: MyBundle\RelationsHandler
      arguments:
      - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
      tags:
      - { name: jms_serializer.handler, type: Relation, direction: serialization, format: json, method: serializeRelation}
      - { name: jms_serializer.handler, type: Relation, direction: deserialization, format: json, method: deserializeRelation}
      - { name: jms_serializer.handler, type: Relation<?>, direction: serialization, format: json, method: serializeRelation}
      - { name: jms_serializer.handler, type: Relation<?>, direction: deserialization, format: json, method: deserializeRelation}
```

This allows you to replace virtual getter methods with `Type("Relation").

If  you also want't to deserialize relation - you should tell each `@Type("Relation")` the classname (`@Type("Relation<FQCN>")`) which it should deserialize to or wrap the metadata driver with one which do it for you.

```
    public function deserializeRelation(JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, $relation, array $type, Context $context)
    {
        $className = isset($type['params'][0]['name']) ? $type['params'][0]['name'] : null;

        if (!class_exists($className, false)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Class name should be explicitly set for deserialization');
        }

        $metadata = $this->manager->getClassMetadata($className);

        if (!is_array($relation)) {
            return $this->manager->getReference($className, $relation);
        }

        $single = false;
        if ($metadata->isIdentifierComposite) {
            $single = true;
            foreach ($metadata->getIdentifierFieldNames() as $idName) {
                $single = $single && array_key_exists($idName, $relation);
            }
        }

        if ($single) {
            return $this->manager->getReference($className, $relation);
        }

        $objects = [];
        foreach ($relation as $idSet) {
            $objects[] = $this->manager->getReference($className, $idSet);
        }

        return $objects;
    }
```

Comment: This feels like a far more well rounded answer, I'll try adopting this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted answer is correct, but requires a lot manual work and is read-only (does not support deserialization). This one is a bit automated, but requires undestanding of jms internals

Comment: @ScayTrase Entities are still lazy loaded when using this approach. Do you know if that can be avoided? Using the accepted answer with virtual props will not cause the entity to load (assuming you are indeed fetching the id).

Comment: @bblue Lazyness is totally up to your configuration and application logic. Entities stay not loaded until you load the field that is not the ID. To awoid lazy loading you can manually prefetch the relations with `select('entity', 'realtion')->leftJoin('entity.relation','relation')` query builder or configure `EAGER` fetch globally for the relation

Comment: @ScayTrase That's exactly my point, I only serialize the ID, but I still see an additional db query. After some research I suppose it could be related to https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/575. I guess that fix has not made it to a stable release yet.

Comment: yeah, try RC release, should be there

Comment: Works like a charm! For anyone else having issues, note that the option to skip initialization is by default turned off. `function __construct($skipVirtualTypeInit = false)`in `JMS/Serializer/SerializationContext.php`

Answer (score 10):

I know this has already been answered but you could also use @Accessor.
This probably (may, I can't be sure) work with deserialization too.

```
/**
 * @Type("Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country")
 * @Groups({"manage"})
 * 
 * @var \Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country
 *
 * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getCountryMinusId",setter="setCountryWithId")
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getCountryMinusId()
{
    if (is_array($this->country) && isset($this->country['id'])) {
        return $this->country['id'];
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @param string $country
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCountryWithId($country)
{
    if (!is_array($this->country)) {
        $this->country = array();
    )

    $this->country['id'] = $country;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use  `@Type` and `@Accessor` annotations:

```
/**
 * @Type("string") 
 * @Accessor(getter="serializeType",setter="setType") 
 */
protected $type;
public function serializeType()
{   
  return $this->type->getId();
}
```

Comment: * you have to return in the function: ` return $this->type->getId();`

Answer (score 1):

The author wants to keep the property name, which doesn't apply to the accepted answer. As far as I understood, the answer by ScayTrase would keep the original property name but has another disadvantage according to the comments: The related object will be fetched if you are using Doctrine ORM `@ManyToOne`, thus decreasing performance.

If you want to keep the original property name, you have to define the `@VirtualProperty` at class level and `@Exclude` the original property. Otherwise, the serialized property name will be derived from the getter method (`countryId` in this case):

```
/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty(
 *     "country",
 *     exp="object.getCountryId()",
 *     options={@Serializer\SerializedName("country")}
 * )
 */
class Ad {
    /**
     * @Serializer\Exclude
     */
    private $country;

    public function getCountryId() {
        return $this->country === null ? null : $this->country->getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can `@inline` `$country` which will serialize its properties into the parent relation. Then you can `@Expose` the Country `$id` and set its `@SerializedName` to `"country"`. Unlike Virtual properties, **both serialization and deserialization will work for inline properties**.

For this to work, you need to use the `@ExclusionPolicy("All")` on each class and judiciously `@Expose` the properties that you need in any of your groups. [This is a more secure policy anyways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

```
/**
 * @ExclusionPolicy("All")
 */
class Ad
{ 

    //...


    /**
     * @Type("Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country")
     * 
     * @Expose()
     * @Inline()
     * @Groups({"manage"})
     *
     * @var \Acme\SearchBundle\Entity\Country
     */
    private $country;


    //...

}
```

```
/**
 * @ExclusionPolicy("All")
 */
class Country
{

    //...

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @Expose()
     * @Groups({"manage"})
     * @SerializedName("country")
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me, `Invalid data "781f8d11-8407-49bd-b826-d98343f18d0c" (string), expected "AppBundle\Entity\Country"`